# Convert 8.3 filename to long filename

Tags: c#, .net, filenames

Have a network location that shows paths in the 8.3 short format.  I need to convert these to long format for use on UNIX.

Since its a network location I need it needs to work with UNC paths.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to converting short to long is [just a Google search away](http://csharparticles.blogspot.com/2005/07/long-and-short-file-name-conversion-in.html). This will work for UNC paths [only on Windows Vista and up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and possible XP w/ some service packs).

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class _Main
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetLongPathName(
        string path,
        StringBuilder longPath,
        int longPathLength
        );

    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder longPath = new StringBuilder(255);
        GetLongPathName(@"\\?\UNC\server\d$\MYTEMP~1\RESOUR~1\sql.txt", longPath, longPath.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine(longPath.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The two MarshalAs attributes are not needed.

Comment: This still doesn't work for my scenario.  I am assuming this is because of my UNC path.  Its a CIFS share on a NetApp filer.  Based on your comment : _This will work for UNC paths only on Windows Vista and up (and possible XP w/ some service packs)._ I assume this might be the problem ?

Comment: How does it fail? What does Marshal::GetLastWin32Error tell you?

Comment: @David indeed. I've removed them now (it was copy-and-paste'd from the link I posted)

Comment: @David Marshal.GetLastWin32Error returns 5 (Access Denied).

Comment: Looks like the token for your process does not have the necessary rights.

Answer (score 2):

There are several functions to convert a 8.3 name to a fullname. I prefer the FileInfo class.

```
string shortName = @"c:\PROGRA~1";
string longName = new FileInfo(shortName).FullName; 
// ==> longname: c:\Program Files
```

this works even with UNC paths:

```
string shortName = @"\\MyComputer\c$\PROGRA~1";
string longName = new FileInfo(shortName).FullName; 
// ==> longname: \\MyComputer\c$\Program Files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use "C:>dir /X" to see the short names
string dosPath = @"C:\Windows\WINDOW~1.LOG";
string winPath = Path.GetFullPath(dosPath);
```